# what are the possible ways to create 3 storage accounts with 3 containers in each one with terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-storage, terraform-provider-azure

am leaning terraform , so I have written code that creates that creates 3 storage accounts with 1 container in each one. So now I need to  modify it to create 3 storage accounts with 3 containers in each one.

```
1) main.tf file 

# creation of storage accounts one for logs and another for custom scripts
# creation of resource group
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "sam_rg" {
  name     = var.resource_group_name
  location = var.location
  tags     = local.tags
}

# using count feature to create 3 storage accounts
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "sampath-storage-accounts" {
  count                     = length(var.storage-account_config)
  name                      = "${count.index}${keys(var.storage-account_config)[count.index]}${lower(var.Environment)}"
  location                  = azurerm_resource_group.sam_rg.location
  resource_group_name       = azurerm_resource_group.sam_rg.name
  account_tier              = var.storage-account_config[keys(var.storage-account_config)[count.index]].account_tier
  account_kind              = var.storage-account_config[keys(var.storage-account_config)[count.index]].account_kind
  account_replication_type  = var.storage-account_config[keys(var.storage-account_config)[count.index]].account_replication_type
  access_tier               = var.storage-account_config[keys(var.storage-account_config)[count.index]].access_tier
  shared_access_key_enabled = var.storage-account_config[keys(var.storage-account_config)[count.index]].shared_access_key_enabled
  min_tls_version           = var.storage-account_config[keys(var.storage-account_config)[count.index]].min_tls_version
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_resource_group.sam_rg
  ]
  tags = local.tags
}

#using count feature to create 3 containers in storage accounts
resource "azurerm_storage_container" "sampath-containers" {
  count                 = length(var.storage_container-config)
  name                  = keys(var.storage_container-config)[count.index]
  storage_account_name  = azurerm_storage_account.sampath-storage-accounts[count.index].name
  container_access_type = var.storage_container-config[keys(var.storage_container-config)[count.index]].container_access_type
}

2).local.tf file 
locals {
  tags = {
    "Environment" = "var.Environment"
    "Project"     = "var.Project"
    "Team"        = "Compliance"
    "Location"    = "data.azurerm_resource_group.sam-rg.location"
  }
}

3). variable.tf file 
variable "resource_group_name" {
  type        = string
  description = "name of esource group whivh was exeisted already in resource group"
}

variable "location" {
  type = string
}

variable "Environment" {
  type        = string
  description = "creation of resources to which environment"
}
variable "Project" {
  type        = string
  description = "reation of resources to which Project"
}

variable "storage-account_config" {
  type = map(object({
    account_tier              = string
    account_kind              = string
    account_replication_type  = string
    access_tier               = string
    shared_access_key_enabled = bool
    min_tls_version           = string
  }))
  description = "storage-account_config"
}


variable "storage_container-config" {
  type = map(object({
    container_access_type = string
  }))
  description = "storage_container-config"
}

4). variable.tfvars file 

# name of esource group whivh was exeisted already in resource group
resource_group_name = "abp-rg-env_dev"

# location
location = "eastus"

# creation of resources to which environment 
Environment = "Development"

# creation of resources to which Project
Project = "ABP-01"

# storage-account_config
storage-account_config = {
    sampath = {        
        account_tier              = "Standard"
        account_kind              = "StorageV2"
        account_replication_type  = "LRS"
        access_tier               = "Hot"
        shared_access_key_enabled = "true"
        min_tls_version           = "TLS1_2"
    }
    sandeep = {
        account_tier              = "Premium"
        account_kind              = "StorageV2"
        account_replication_type  = "GRS"
        access_tier               = "Cool"
        shared_access_key_enabled = false
        min_tls_version           = "TLS1_2"
    }
    aravind = {
        account_tier              = "Standard"
        account_kind              = "StorageV2"
        account_replication_type  = "ZRS"
        access_tier               = "Cool"
        shared_access_key_enabled = false
        min_tls_version           = "TLS1_2"
    }
}

storage_container-config = {
    container01 = {       
        container_access_type = "private"
    }
    container02 = {        
        container_access_type = "blob"
    }
    container03 = {        
        container_access_type = "private"
    }
}
```

so my point is that, is it possible to do with count with out using for_each , by adding for expression to loop, I couldn't figure out what to write in for expression,
Please help me to create 3 storage accounts with 3 containers in each one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***The following code worked for me using count .***

**variables.tf**

```
 variable "containers_list" {
  type = list
  default = [{ name = "sa1container1", access_type = "private" }, {name = "sa1container2", access_type = "private" },{name = "sa1container3", access_type = "private" }]
 }

 variable "Storage_list" {
  type = list
  default = ["kavvst1", "kavvst2","kavvst3"]
 }
```

**main.tf**

```
#Define locals which is the product of storage accounts list  and containers list number.

locals {
  flat_list = setproduct(range(length(var.Storage_list)), var.containers_list)
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "storage_account" {
  count                = length(var.Storage_list)
  name                 = var.Storage_list[count.index]
  resource_group_name  = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location             = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_tier         = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
}
```

// Create containers according to container list for each of the storage account

```
resource "azurerm_storage_container" "container" {
  count                 = length(local.flat_list)
  name                  = local.flat_list[count.index][1].name
  container_access_type = local.flat_list[count.index][1].access_type
  storage_account_name  = azurerm_storage_account.storage_account[local.flat_list[count.index][0]].name
}
```

***Executed successfully on **`terraform apply`*****

---

[image]

---

***I have given Three storage accounts in variable list and they are created.***

[image]

***3 containers created in each of these storage accounts:***

[image]

[image]

[image]

***`Also check this`*** [How to create multiple storage accounts with specific container count in terraform - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74559414/how-to-create-multiple-storage-accounts-with-specific-container-count-in-terrafo/74628035#74628035) ***`for using foreach loop.`***

Comment: thanks @kavyaS, you helped me to learn about "setproduct", I used this same method to work with modules